# Setting value from Derivered class, while accesing same value from base class

Tags: c++, box2d, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am getting an issue for retrieving BaseClass correct enum value.

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    enum EntityId {
        EN_NONE = 0,
        EN_PLAYER = 1,
        EN_PLATFORM,
        EN_GROUND,
        EN_OBSTACLE,
        EN_OTHER
    };
    void setEntityId(EntityId id) { _Entityid = id; }
    EntityId getEntityId() { return _Entityid; }
protected:
    EntityId _Entityid;
};
```

and

```
class DeriveredClassA : public SomeClass, public BaseClass {....};
class DeriveredClassB : public SomeClass, public BaseClass {....};
```

The initialization goes like this

`DeriveredClassA->setEntityId(BaseClass::EntityId::EN_PLAYER);`

`DeriveredClassB->setEntityId(BaseClass::EntityId::EN_OBSTACLE);`

Which is placed into a different vector list correspoinding to that enum.

However, I am forced to use `void*` to do `static_casts` cats...

Like this:

```
BaseClass* EA = static_cast<BaseClass*>(bodyUserDataA); //bodyUserDataA and bodyUserDataB are both void*
BaseClass* EB = static_cast<BaseClass*>(bodyUserDataB);
```

And I am trying to retrieve using `EA->getEntityId()` and `EB->getEntityId()` so I could check which one is EN_PLAYER, which one is EN_GROUND and etc. So then I could up-class from base into derivered class and do other stuff with it.

Tried using with virtual, however somehow I am receiving 2 copies of _EntityID, which can be either the same or DIFFERENT between my Derivered and BaseClass of that one object.

Moreover, I can't cast right away into DeriveredClass, since the code checking would be huge, due to many different types of DeriveredClass'es (DeriveredClassA, DeriveredClassB, DeriveredClassC, DeriveredClassD) with their corresponding vector list.

My question is that How I need setup correctly both Base and Derivered class, so that I could access _EntityID from Baseclass which is the same of that DeriveredClass? My main problem might is that I used incorectly virtual functions, so I left on default to understand my issue.

P.S. This is mainly my c++ issue, other tags are added due to I am using game engine and physics engine for this case.

Comment: You may be interested in [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). This cast is designed to cast between types related by inheritance.

Comment: That's the point, I can't use dynamic_casts, gives me a error of "the operand of a pointer dynamic_cast must be a pointer to a complete class name"....

Comment: what is an `EntityInfo`? We don't know how it relates to BaseClass or DerivedClassA/B.

Comment: TL;DR: [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: @RyanP Sorry, I fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want your code to look more like this:

```
class Entity
{
public:
    enum Type {
        EN_NONE = 0,
        EN_PLAYER = 1,
        EN_PLATFORM,
        EN_GROUND,
        EN_OBSTACLE,
        EN_OTHER
    };

    Type getType() { return _type; }

protected:
    Entity(Type type): _type(type) {}

private:
    const Type _type;
};
```

Then your derived classes and usage of this base would be more like:

```
class PlayerEntity: public Entity, public SomeClass
{
public:
    PlayerEntity(std::string name): Entity(EN_PLAYER), _name(name) {}
    std::string getName() const { return _name; }

private:
    std::string _name;
};

class PlatformEntity: public Entity, public SomeClass
{
public:
    PlatformEntity(): Entity(EN_PLATFORM) {}
};
```

Initialization is then done like:

```
int main()
{
    PlatformEntity platform;
    std::vector<PlatformEntity> platforms(platform);
    std::vector<PlayerEntity> players;
    players.emplace_back("Bob");
    players.emplace_back("Alice");
    players.emplace_back("Ook");
}
```

Access from user-data could then look like this:

```
// bodyUserDataA and bodyUserDataB are both void*
Entity* const EA = static_cast<Entity*>(bodyUserDataA);
Entity* const EB = static_cast<Entity*>(bodyUserDataB);

switch (EA->getType())
{
    case Entity::EN_PLAYER:
    {
        PlayerEntity* player = static_cast<PlayerEntity*>(EA);
        std::cout << "Found player: " << player->getName();
        break;
    }
    case Entity::EN_OTHER:
        ...
    default:
        break;
}
```